# wants to retrieve data from two table on conditional base....so having issues need guidness

Tags: mysql

i have two tables vms_vendor_job_submission table as main, and second vms_offer table, main table primary key is foreign key in second table, so i need all those record which have job_id=101 and resume_status=7 from main table and it should have no entry in second table or if entry exist then its status should be 2(rejected).

```
select s.*
from vms_vendor_job_submission s left join
     vms_offer o 
     on s.id = o.submission_id and
        o.status = '2'
where s.job_id=".$_GET['job_id']." and s.resume_status='7'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it....and working fine

```
"SELECT s.* FROM vms_vendor_job_submission s 
LEFT JOIN vms_offer o 
ON s.id = o.submission_id 
WHERE s.job_id = 101 and if(s.id =o.submission_id, o.status = 2 and s.resume_status = '7',s.resume_status = '7')";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the logic you seem to want:

```
select s.*
from vms_vendor_job_submission s left join
     vms_offer o
     on s.id = o.submission_id 
where s.job_id=".$_GET['job_id']." and
      s.resume_status = '7' and
      (o.status is null or o.status = '2')
```

Comment: its returning zero row.....actually what i want is pick all records s table against the conditions and then check those in the o table if there is any match then check the status of that match if its status is 2 then show that record otherwise hide that.....and if there is no match in second table then display it.....u got my point right?